# Getting string from a different function in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a class that accesses an API and returns the value in the API:

```
import React from 'react';

class UserList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { customer: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch('https://surpriserecommenderapi.herokuapp.com/recommend?customer_id=alakbar@gmail.com', {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then(response => {
            // *** Check for HTTP success
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            // *** Read the body, parse it as JSON
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(({ prediction }) => this.setState({ customer: prediction }))
        .catch(error => {
            // ...*** handle/report error...
        });
    }

    render() {

        const customers = this.state.customer.map((item, i) => (
            <div>
                <h1>{item}</h1>
            </div>
        ));

        return (
            <div id="layout-content" className="layout-content-wrapper">
                <div className="panel-list">{customers}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

`{customers}` returns a string "Rome" to display on the website.
I am trying to call this in App.js. I am able to call UserList and display "Rome" however, I want to create an if statement that checks what the value of what is displayed. Like this:

```
const recommended = <UserList></UserList>
console.log(recommended);

  const recommendedPackage = () => {
    if(recommended === "Roam in Rome"){
      return(
        <div>Recommended package: Roam in Rome</div>
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <div>No recommended package</div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Am I getting this right, you are trying to compare a component with a string? `<UserList></UserList>` is a call to `React.createElement()`, which is a function, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should implement the required logic in the `UserList` class, with some sort of conditional rendering. Maybe something like:

```js
class UserList extends React.Component {
  ...
  parseCustomers() {
    return (
      this.state.customers.map(item => {
        if (item === "Rome") {
          // logic here
        } else {
          // logic here
        }
      });
    );
  }

  render() {
    const customers = this.parseCustomers();
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense!